# UITable View Index List

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have to add default UITable View Index List and want to make it customize according to requirement like change bar width, font size and title color.

Right now when i have added it on table view the Index title is not taking the whole width of table and it showing in the middle but i need to use device height according to the device size.

Comment: Your question is pretty vague. I can only guide you to the correct section of Apple Docs : Configuring the Table Index
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW91

Comment: @Dean:Thanks for reply but i wanted to explain is: i have to use Index list as we have default in Contacts on iPhone devices. If we use this in iPhone 6, the index list does not take complete height of device rather it looks in middle.
I need to customize Index list, in which i can change font size and text color of title and also need to change the bar width of index list.

Answer (score 0):

you can get cell based on store index path

```
let cell = tableview.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
```

and now cell to access controls of cell like lable font color etc,.